# Rust/Wasm: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'env' in

Tags: webpack, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to port a [wrapper for this crate](https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel.git) into wasm. My current toolchain is:

- wasm-pack
- webpack
- wasm-bindgen

A bit more info on the build system:

In my rust crate (which is a `--lib` crate), I only call `wasm-pack build --target browser`. This will create a `pkg` folder containing wasm blobs and associated js files. No complaints from the compiler here.

Then, inside `pkg`, I run `npm link` (just once).

Then, `cargo generate --git https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack-template` creates the required web-app boilerplate. Inside the folder generated by this command, I run `npm link schnorrkel-js` to make it visible. `npm run start` runs the webpack dev server.

initial tests like binding simple calculation functions and alert work fine.

Everything breaks when I start using *some* (not **any**) functions from the mentioned crate ([example](https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel/blob/master/src/sign.rs#L190)). Unfortunately, the error message that I get is quite un-informative and does not help at all:

```
Entrypoint main = bootstrap.js
[../pkg/schnorrkel_js.js] 3.53 KiB {0} [built]
[../pkg/schnorrkel_js_bg.wasm] 93.7 KiB {0} [built]
    + 27 hidden modules

ERROR in ../pkg/schnorrkel_js_bg.wasm
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'env' in '.../schnorrkel-js/pkg'
 @ ../pkg/schnorrkel_js_bg.wasm
 @ ../pkg/schnorrkel_js.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./bootstrap.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./bootstrap.js
```

What is the cause of this? I have a strong guess that some underlying functionality is not portable to wasm but which one exactly, why, and what is the error message trying to say?

---

notes:

- I am using the latest rust nightly version (`rustc 1.34.0-nightly (d17318011 2019-02-07)`)
- rest of the setup steps are taken directly from the [Rust and Webassembly book](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/setup.html).
- Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "schnorrkel-js"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
schnorrkel = { git = "https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel.git" }
```

Example code:

```
#[wasm_bindgen] 
pub fn verify(signature: &[u8], message: &[u8], pubkey: &[u8]) -> bool {
    let sig = match Signature::from_bytes(signature) {
        Ok(some_sig) => some_sig,
        Err(_) => return false
    };
    let pk = match PublicKey::from_bytes(pubkey) {
        Ok(some_pk) => some_pk,
        Err(_) => return false
    };

    // works up until here if I return a boolean. 
    // calling this breaks everything.
    pk.verify_simple(SIGNING_CTX, message, &sig)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this could be an issue with the C code used by the `clear_on_drop` dependency, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/763).

Try enabling the `nightly` feature on the `schnorrkel` crate, which in turn enables the `nightly` feature on `clear_on_drop` that disables its usage of C. On your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
schnorrkel = { git = "https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel.git", features = ["nightly"] }
```

Alternatively, you can use `wasm2wat` (there's [an online version](https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wasm2wat/)) on your compiled `.wasm` binary to inspect which `env` import is failing.